# C# .NET Core3 XHR Request in loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, .net-core, foreach

I have a function that calls XHR requests in a loop. I would like to know if there is any other more efficient and ideal way to do this.

```
public async Task<List<StationDevice>> GetMeterReportDevices(string projectId)
{
            List<StationDevice> devices = new List<ReportDevice>();

            Project project = this.projectService.GetProject(projectId);

            // Let's say there are 10000 stations
            List<Station> stations = await this.stationService.GetStations(project.ProjectId);

            foreach (Station station in stations)
            {
                // Let's say there are 1000 station devices
                List<StationDevice> stationDevices = await this.stationService.GetStationDevices(project.ProjectId, station.StationId);
                devices.AddRange(stationDevices);
            }

            return devices;
}
```

I was wondering how I could make this faster and efficient as this is taking a huge amount of time.
If you are wondering, the XHR request is being made to a 3rd party API, so there is nothing much that we can do from that side.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
public async Task<List<StationDevice>> GetMeterReportDevices(string projectId)
{
            List<StationDevice> devices = new List<ReportDevice>();

            Project project = this.projectService.GetProject(projectId);

            // Let's say there are 10000 stations
            List<Station> stations = await this.stationService.GetStations(project.ProjectId);
            var tasks = new List<Task<List<StationDevices>>>();
            foreach (Station station in stations)
            {
               tasks.Add(this.stationService.GetStationDevices(project.ProjectId, station.StationId));
            }

            foreach (var t in tasks)
            {
                // Let's say there are 1000 station devices
                List<StationDevice> stationDevices = await t;
                devices.AddRange(stationDevices);
            }

            return devices;
}
```

This way you first fire all the requests and then start to wait one by one while the others process.

Comment: This is still slow. However like democracy, I reckon this is the best that we have.